# Exist a linear Transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $T(1,-1)=(1,0), T(2,-1)=(0,1), T(-3,2)=(1,1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I take this vectos because his combination is a base for R^{2}

$(1,-1)$ and $(-3,2)$

Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$

Let's see if these vectors are linearly independent.

Consider: $\alpha(1,-1) +\beta(-3,2)=(0,0)$

Then,

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -3\\
-1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$

This implies that the vectors are linearly independent.

Then I need to see what the conditions are for these vectors to generate $R^{2}$.

Consider: $\alpha(1,-1) +\beta(-3,2)=(a,b)$ Then,

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -3\\
-1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\
b
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2a-3b\\
-a-b
\end{pmatrix}$

Then, we can conclude this:

$T(a,b)=T(\alpha(1,-1)+\beta(-3,2))=\alpha T(1,-1)+\beta T(-3,2)=(-2a-3b)(1,0)+(-a-b)(1,1)=(-3a-4b,-a-b)$,

In other words

$T(a,b)=(-3a-4b,-a-b)$

But if I substitute the values of linear transformation, this happens.

$T(1,-1)=(-3+4,-1+1)=(1,0)$.

$T(2,-1)=(-6+4,-2+1)=(-2,-1)\neq(0,1)$

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear transformation must map $0$ to $0$. So we try to combine the $0$ vector from the arguments by using the linearity:
\begin{align}
T(1,-1) + T(2,-1) + T(-3,2) 
&= T(1+2+(-3), -1 + (-1) + 2) \\
&= T(0,0) \\
&= (1,0)+ (0,1) + (1,1) \\
&= (2,2) \\
&\ne 0
\end{align}

Comment: :O Thankkssssss!!!!!! excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $(-3,2)=-(1,-1)-(2,-1)$ so that by linearity, $T(-3,2)$ should equal $-T(1,-1)-T(2,-1)=-(1,0)-(0,1)=(-1,-1)$, but $T(-3,2)$ is given as $(1,1)$, so there can be no such linear transformation.